# Let G be a non-Abelian group such that $|G| \le 15$ with proper subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $G=H\times K$. Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $D_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a non-Abelian group such that $|G| \le 15$ with proper subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $G=H\times K$. Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $D_6$.

I understand that the two subgroups must be $H=\{e,r_3\}$ and $K=\{e,r_2,r_4,f,r_2f,r_4f\}$ in $D_6$. I also know that $D_6$ has order $12$ but I do not understand why the less than or equal to $15$ is necessary. 
I'm really not understanding why this must be always isomorphic to $D_6$ no matter the $G$. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need $|G| \leq 15$ because it's false if you allow $|G|=16$.

Comment: Question into the question body, not in the title, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why $\le 15$? Because the next example, the product of a cyclic group of order $2$ and either the dihedral or quaternion group of order $8$, has order $16$.

The way to look at this? We have a product $H\times K$, both nontrivial. In order for the group to be non-abelian, one of the factors must itself be non-abelian. WLOG, let that non-abelian factor be $H$. The smallest non-abelian group $S_3$ has order $6$, and the smallest nontrivial group $\mathbb{Z}/2$ has order $2$. Those are the only groups that fit, so that's the only option of that order.

Increasing the order... $13$ is prime. $14=7\cdot 2$, and there's no non-abelian group of order $7$. $15=5\cdot 3$, and there are no non-abelian options there. We have only one option up to order $15$, as desired.

The least trivial part? Showing that the product $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_6$ on the hexagon. That comes up because the $180^\circ$ rotation commutes with everything.

Comment: Might you need also show that the other 2 non-abelian groups of order 12 **cannot** possibly be written as such a direct product?  Or is that clear for some reason?

Comment: It's clear because we started with the product. There's only one (up to automorphism) non-abelian group of order $6$, only one group of order $2$, and only one way to build a direct product.

Comment: Yeah, that is clear.

Comment: @jmerry So, does this process of elimination work as a proof for the problem once it is shown that the product is isomorphic to D6?

Comment: Yes, it does. You may want to expand some parts if you're writing more formally (e.g. this Lemma: The direct product of two abelian groups is abelian), but it's all there.